# Syntax Error when call Error.constructor with a string including spaces

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried the following code in firefox & chrome & Node.js:

```js
Error.constructor.call({}, 'specified string'); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Error.constructor.call({}, 'specified '); // work well
Error.constructor.call({}, 'specified'); // work well
```

I wonder the reason JS interpreter giving me that Error. It seems that eval() is called with the second parameter, but I really don't know what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `Error.constructor` is actually `Object.constructor`:

```
> Error.constructor === Object.constructor
true
```

Second, `Object.constructor` can be used to create a function:

```
> f = Object.constructor('foo', 'bar', 'return "hello " + foo + " and " + bar;')
[Function: anonymous]
> f('Alice', 'Bob')
'hello Alice and Bob'
```

where the last parameter is the function body and the previous parameters are function parameters.

Finally, your code:

```js
Error.constructor.call({}, 'specified string');
```

means you are calling `Object.constructor` to create a function with a function body `specified string`. The function body `specified string` is a piece of invalid JavaScript code, hence the error.

Comment: Really Amazing. I actually didn't konw that ```Error.constructor === Object.constructor```. I attempt to implement a custom error inheriting Error, and faced this problem.

Comment: I wonder why `Object.constructor` can be used to create a function, are there cases where this is actually useful?

Comment: @CristianTraìna Because constructors are just functions. Compare with the result of `new (Object.constructor('x', 'this.x = x'))('myValue')`

Answer (score 0):

Yang, I might misunderstand your problem but if you just want to throw an error you can use 
`throw new Error('Something is broken')` as in this case also the Error constructor is called and you don't need to use .call explicitly as you anyways not passing any context there.

Hope this might help.